# Windows: How to start application when the other finishes

Tags: windows, script, cmd.exe

I would like to launch an application automatically, always when some other application finishes. Is it even possible to perform?

My specific situation is: User connects to remote desktop and then, some Iexplorer window with specific page must occurre.

So far, I found solution using `start /wait`:

```
start /wait prog1.exe
start /wait prog2.exe
```

but this solution is not good enough since the first program must be always opened via the cmd script.

I tried to perform this task using task scheduler but unfortunately I could not find proper interruption or activity that would meet my needs.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have made 90 percent of the way to a solution.
If the connection method is via RDP, one can start off a program when a user logs in.
Put the "start" commands in a .BAT/.CMD file and via "Advanced" tab of the RDP invoke it as part of user log in.

Comment: Thank you for your reaction, unfortunately maybe I did not formulate my demands clearly: I need program to run on the local computer NO on the remote one (NO on the computer the user tries to connect to).
The time sequence should be:
1) User connects to the remote computer
2) in the very moment, on the LOCAL machine program P is executed
3) user terminates remote connection
4) in the very moment, on the LOCAL machine program Q is executed

Do you have any suggestion for this situation, please?

Comment: If the commands need running on local machine, one can try "CALL" command. "CALL prog1.exe" will wait until prog1 finishes and only then continue to next command (prog2.exe).

Comment: Actually, your comment helped me in the solving the situation. I combined Visual Basic simple script and CALL command to achieve the solution. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If PowerShell is an option, you could use Task Scheduler to start this script in a hidden PowerShell window.

This will watch for the `mstsc.exe` process to start, then open `notepad.exe` when each `mstsc.exe` process exits.

```
# The action to be performed for every new process event.
$action = {
    $target = $EventArgs.NewEvent.TargetInstance
    if($target.Name -eq 'mstsc.exe') {
        # Run action as a job in order to handle multiple new calc.exe
        # processes. Otherwise, the script will be blocked waiting for
        # the first calc.exe to exit.
        $jobScript = {
                param($ProcessId) 
                (Get-Process -Id $ProcessID).WaitForExit()
                notepad.exe
            }
        Start-Job -ScriptBlock $jobScript -ArgumentList $target.ProcessId
    }
}

$query = @"
Select * From __InstanceCreationEvent within 3
Where TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Process'
"@

Register-WMIEvent -query $query -Action $action -sourceIdentifier "New Process"
```